# How to get event name in event handler

Tags: c#, .net

I'm curious if is possible to get event name in event handler?
I'm pretty sure, that it's possible, can you help me find solution?
Ex:

```
public class Boy
{
    public event EventHandler Birth;
    public event EventHandler Die;
}

public class Mother
{
    public Mother()
    {
        Boy son = new Boy();
        son.Birth += son_Handler;
        son.Die += son_Handler;
    }

    void son_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // how to get event name (Birth/Die)?
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? What is your use case? This smells like a bad design...

Comment: You can create a different handler for each event, thus making it unnecessary.

Comment: you can pass that info while triggering the event using EventArgs.otherwise I don't see any way from getting the event name from the event handler because it doesn't know anything about the event.

Comment: I think the goal is to inform the mother when the boy is born and when he dies, although I'm sure she doesn't need the boy to tell her when he is born, she'll likely realise that herself somehow!

Comment: I would also suggest that you only create the boy when he is born, until that point he is null!  No need for a birth event.

Comment: Well I have 2 basic layers in app. Client + Core and they use two way communication. Core work with hw devices and in hw devices occour events and I need to call client with event notification and I'm to lazy write 50+ event handlers with the same one line...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm curious if is possible to get event name in event handler?

No, it's not. The event handler is just a method. It could be invoked directly, not in the context of *any* event.

What you *could* do is have:

```
public Mother()
{
    Boy son = new Boy();
    son.Birth += (sender, e) => Handler("Birth", sender, e);
    son.Die += (sender, e) => Handler("Die", sender, e);
}

void Handler(string description, object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log("I'm in the {0} event", description);
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to inherit `EventArgs` class and add necessary fields.

```
class MyArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string What { get; set; }
}

delegate void MyHandler(object sender, MyArgs e);

. . .

var myEvent = birthEvent;
if (myEvent != null)
    myEvent(new MyArgs { What = "Birth"};
```